# Time complexity in terms of theta notation

Tags: notation, algorithms, asymptotics, analysis-of-algorithms

sum= 0;
for (i = n; i > o; i = i/3)
   for (j = 0; j < n^3; j++)
                 sum++;

what is the time complexity (in Θ- notation) in terms of n?

so far, i've gotten to this point: 
The running time is O(n^3).Because the for loops’ conditions are depend on n and n
2, respectively
i don't feel right about it. would appreciate any help, thanks.

Comment: Do not post the same question several times.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any loop conditions on $n$ or (did you mean)$n^2$.  The $j$ loop executes $n^3$ times, the $i$ loop less (how much?) than that.  Is the $j$ loop inside the $i$ loop?  If so (and it looks like it) you need to multiply the number of cycles.

Comment: i meant n^3. the j loop is inside the i loop.

Comment: So how many times does the $i$ loop run?  For each one, you get $n^3$ runs of the $j$ loop.

Comment: the i loop runs i/3 times i guess?

Comment: No, it divides $i$ by $3$ each time through.

Comment: so is (n^3) ∈Θ(logn) the right answer?

Comment: No, the runtime is $n^3 \log n$.  You do $\log_3 n$ iterations of the $i$ loop (and $\log_3 \sim \log_2$).  For each of those you do $n^3$ of the inner loop.